# Junit test with inheritance, good or bad? Discussion

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I'm looking for opinions to test different implementations of an interface with as easy and as little code as possible. I've implemented one of many ways to to this. I will use Inheritance to make it possible.

If you search the web for this, you will find numerous of articles that tells you that this is wrong to include inheritance because it's harder to read and understand and that tests "always" should be one long block of code and it dose not matter if there is a lot of duplicated code.
One of the perks of testing this way is that it's easy to test the difference between the implementations with the help of the abstract methods that the testImpls has to implement.

Anyway I would like your opinon on my way to test in this case two different implementations of one interface. The difference between the impls is that ImplCloud puts an package in the cloud while implLocal puts it on disk.

We will have an assert class called SomeImplAsserts and impl Local and Cloud. 
The test will be constructed with three test classes filled with comments and some pseudo code to explain.

`SomeImplAsserts.class`
`ImplCloudTest.class`
`ImplLocalTest.class`

```
public abstract class SomeImplAsserts {
  // Variables that booth implementations need.
  private PathGetter pathGetter;

  // Abstract helper methods. 
  abstract public String getLocalPackagePath(PathGetter pathGetter);

  // Common setup method.
  @Before
  public void setUp() {
  //Setup that's equal for for all impls will be done here.
  }

  @Test
  public void testPackageContent() throws IOException {
  // Place for common assert, asserts where we expect the same value from our implementations will be placed here.

  String pathToPackage = getLocalPackagePath(pathGetter);
  assertEquals("/someTempPath/package.zip", pathToPackage);
  unzip(pathToPackage);

  //asserts on package content.     

  }
  //Common utility methods.
  public void unzip(String abc) throws IOException {
  // unzips the package
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() {
    //Tear down of all tests will be done here.
  }
}
```

Impl Cloud:

```
public class ImplCloudTest extends SomeImplAsserts {

@Override
public String getLocalPackagePath(PathGetter pathGetter) {
  // A place where you could write specific asserts for this impl.
  // This Impl puts an package in the cloud, in order to run tests on the content off the file
  // we would like to put it on disk.

  String url = pathGetter.getPath();
  assertTrue(isUrl(url));

  //Create temp dir and download file to it.

  Path temp = Files.createTempDirectory("someTempPath");
  URI u = URI.create(exportUrl);

  InputStream in = u.toURL().openStream();
  String pathToFile = temp.toString().concat("/" + exportUrl.substring(exportUrl.lastIndexOf("/")));
  Files.copy(in, Paths.get(pathToFile));

  return pathToFile;
}
}
```

Impl Local:

```
public class ImplaLocalTest extends SomeImplAsserts {

@Override
public String getLocalPackagePath(PathGetter pathGetter) {
  // this impl puts the file at the disk to begin with. No need to download it.
  String localPath = pathGetter.getPath();
  assertFalse(isUrl(localPath));

  return localPath;
}
}
```

So what do you think, is this a good way to test different impls or would it be better to simplify it with two to tests with duplicated asserts?

Comment: IMHO, it's OK to do it like that

Comment: When you say "heritage", do you mean "inheritance"?

Comment: @Andy Turner yep, you are right!

Comment: OO why a down vote?  :( please tell whats wrong.

Comment: What is a "good way" can lead to mainly opinion-based answers. It is not a good starting point for a question; it is more of an invitation to a discussion. Because, when it is about design, there are mostly more than one good ways.

Comment: @Jägermeister I actually  wanted opinion based answers. As you stated, there is more than one good way. And I want to learn and evaluate them. Maybe I did put this question in wrong forum?

Comment: @Jägermeister I've edited the question. Thanks for your opinion!

Answer (score 1):

There is no right or wrong answer here; it comes down to preference and the precise situation. Here are a couple of thoughts about the general approach (full disclosure: I am strongly in the "composition beats inheritance" camp):

There are two types of thing that you've got in your base class:

- Utility methods: these don't really belong in the class - just put those in a separate class, and create an instance of that in your concrete test classes.
- Setup/tear down-type methods: these *could* be in a base class, but it's inflexible, in the same way that inheritance is generally inflexible in Java: you only get to extend one class, so you're a bit stuck if you want to add more.

  JUnit4 provides [Fixtures](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Test-fixtures), which can be used to set up common things; they are sort of like mixins. The syntax is a bit more verbose, but with that verbosity comes flexibility.